# how to push new object into ng-repeat using orderBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

below is my code:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: 'id' track by $index ">
    </li>
```

i am having trouble in ng-repeat orders when pushing new data. it just push randomly. not as i expected orderBy 'id'
i have tried push, shift, unshift nothing works.

Comment: Can you `console.log(people);`? And is the **id** property a string or a number? If it's a string, it could cause ordering to be much different.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any way you can provide a code example so we can run it? 
If not, try putting this at the end of the function that pushes to the array:
`$scope.$apply();`.

Comment: This answer would make more sense as a comment on the question asked

Comment: Agreed...but I'm lacking in reputation. :)

Comment: my bad forgot you needed 50 rep, I feel kind of bad now heh